# ionic3/angular 4 : Injecting a service in another service not working

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ionic3

I am trying to make a simple use of a service within another service  (not into a Component) with Dependency Injection in ionic3/angular4. I thought I had understood how to do it in theory, but in practise I have been struglying several days...

Here is my configuration :

```
cli packages:
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
    @ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

and this is my **tsconfig.json** file (as I have gone throught some threads suggesting compiling options could have some effects on injection behavior)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

In my **app.module.ts**, I have registered some Services by importing their associated modules : *NgLoggerModule* & *IonicStorageModule*, others by adding them to providers array :  *SettingsStorageProvider* & *TMDbApiProvider* :

```
@NgModule({
....
imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    NgLoggerModule.forRoot(Level.LOG)
],
providers: [
    ....
    SettingsStorageProvider,
    TMDbApiProvider
]
```

This is my **SettingsStorageProvider** class where I can make use of *storage* & *logger* services without problem :

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsStorageProvider {

    constructor(public storage: Storage, public logger: Logger) {
        this.logger.log('Hello SettingsStorageProvider');
    }

    public saveSettings(_settings: SettingsModel){
    .... }

    public loadSettings(): Promise<SettingsModel> {
    ....}
}
```

This is my **TMDbApiProvider** class where I cannot make use of injected  services *Logger* or *SettingsStorageProvider* even thought they seem to be correctly registered in **app.module.ts** :

```
@Injectable()
export class TMDbApiProvider {

static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
}
    constructor(public settingsStorage: SettingsStorageProvider, public http: Http, 
    public logger: Logger) {
     if (settingsStorage == null)
         console.log('TMDbApiProvider:constructor-->settingsStorage is NULL !!!');
     if (logger  == null)
         console.log('TMDbApiProvider:constructor-->logger is NULL !!!');
     if (http == null)
         console.log('TMDbApiProvider:constructor-->http is NULL !!!');
}

    searchMovies(movieName) {
        this.settingsStorage.loadSettings().then((_settings) => {
        .....
            var url = Config.data.tmdb_searchService + encodeURI(movieName) + '&'+Config.data.tmdb_apiKey+'&'+Config.data.tmdb_language+_userSettings.getLanguage();
            var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());

            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

I have no errors at compile time, but at runtime, I got the following debug logs I have put in the constructor :

> tmdb-api.ts:30 TMDbApiProvider:constructor-->logger is NULL !!!
>
> tmdb-api.ts:34 TMDbApiProvider:constructor-->http is NULL !!!

and the following error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.settingsStorage.loadSettings is not a function
TypeError: _this.settingsStorage.loadSettings is not a function
    at tmdb-api.ts:48
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at TMDbApiProvider.webpackJsonp.171.TMDbApiProvider.searchMovies
```

If I invert the order of the injected services in the constructor :

```
@Injectable()
export class TMDbApiProvider {

    constructor(public http: Http, public logger: Logger,
    public settingsStorage: SettingsStorageProvider) {
```

I got different debug logs I have put in the constructor :

> TMDbApiProvider:constructor-->settingsStorage is NULL !!!
>   tmdb-api.ts:31 TMDbApiProvider:constructor-->logger is NULL !!!

and the error has also changed :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadSettings' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadSettings' of undefined
```

It seems that only the first service called into **TMDbApiProvider** constructor is injected.

Anyone has ever faced this strange behavior ?
Thank you in advance for any help you could provide to me.

[15/08/2017]
Here is a complementary information for my problem:

The root "NgModule" with the "declarations", "imports", "entryComponents" & "providers" of myApp :
[NgModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DinMZ.gif) 
and a view of the injector graph of myApp using "Augury" Chrome Extension :
[Injector Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juxr4.gif)

Strangely, "TMDbAPIProvider" declared as a Provider in root "NgModule" is not part of the injector graph...
Do someone know why this could be ?
Thank you in advance for your help (it's driving me nuts !).

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you're calling `new TMDbApiProvider(someValueOfAnyType)` somewhere, instead of using DI.

Comment: Thank you for you guess @JBNizet. 
But I use DI for TMDbApiProvider in the 'MoviesHomePage' 
Component :
`export class MoviesHomePage {
 
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private logger: Logger,
      public tmdbApi: TMDbApiProvider) {....`

Comment: OK, it seems that declaring the "get" function as a static function was the reason I coundn't inject this service in another provider: `static get parameters() {
        return [[Http]];
    }` but I don't really understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You **must remove** the `static` keyword on `parameters()` method if you need to use that service through `DI`.That is by design.But if you need to use  `Static` methods then you don't need to instantiate that class through `DI`.You can use it like below when you need it on the component:

```
import { TMDbApiProvider } from './TMDbApiProvider';

export class YourComponent {

    constructor() {
        // This is just an example of accessing the static members of a class.
        // Note: we didn't inject the service, nor manually instantiate it 
        let value = TMDbApiProvider.parameters();
     }
  }
```